# Get ajax data in symfony controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm using a library from dhtmlx scheduler, my `start_date` is coming from an `event`, which is simply an xml file which has a `start_date` node. I can do an `alert(star_date)` and it return `Wed Dec 23 2015 09:47:00 GMT+0100 (CET)`

I want to retrieve data (`start_date`) from an ajax request:

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onClick", function (id, e){
var event = scheduler.getEvent(id);
var start_date = event.start_date;

$.ajax({
    url: Routing.generate('admin_event_edit', {id : id}),
    type: "POST",
    data: { id : 'id', start_date : 'start_date'},
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var route = Routing.generate('admin_event_edit', {id : id});
        window.location.href = route;
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error');
       }
});
```

In my controller I'm doing:

```
$startDate = ($request->request->get('start_date');
```

But my `$startDate` is empty.

How can I access the start date?

Comment: use dataType as you want

Comment: Show code what exactly is `start_date`

Comment: Does `start_date` contains object or is it string?

Comment: `start_date` is a string

Comment: i used `dataType : "json"` but now the request doesn't success

Comment: Does `$request->request->get('id')` return data?

Comment: No even id is  empty. and `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` returns `false`

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is in using single quotes instead of double when building json data, try using like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: Routing.generate('admin_event_edit', {id : id}),
    type: "POST",
    data: { id : "id", start_date : "start_date"},
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var route = Routing.generate('admin_event_edit', {id : id});
        window.location.href = route;
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

But here you also trying to submit simple strings `'id'` `'start_date'`, you probably want to send variable values `data: { id : id, start_date : start_date}`

Comment: Thanks, but im getting an error alert . If im using `dataType : "text"` there is no error but i still dont have any data in my controler.
I think my  `window.location.href` is not good. Because just before being redirect, i can in the profiler that the `AJAX_REQUEST` become red.

Comment: hello, i made it to work by changing things : No quote  fore id and start_date; And the redirection was wrong because i tried to send datas to a route then move to this route. But when the data weren't stored in redirection route (because already sent)
I try to save data from an  `$startDate = ($request->request->get('start_date');` into a .txt file, and the value is correctly saved. Now i'm facing another problem : i can't persist an entity from an ajax request. I'll do research and create another question if i can't do it. Thanks, merry xMas.